# flask - access 500 internal server errors in production

Tags: python, flask, error-handling

When I run my flask app locally and I get an Internal Server Error, I can look in the console and see what the error is so that I can debug.

When I get an Internal Server Error on my production server, however, I check the journalctl -xe and the error is not there. Where is it?

producion setup: nginx, gunicorn, ubuntu, digitalocean

desired behavior: to show errors (that show locally) in journalctl or some other logger

Comment: Don't just repost [your closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64657403/flask-where-are-errors-stored-in-production) question! Fix the original!

Comment: I did fix it. It's still closed. That's why I posted this one.

Comment: You have to supply **all** information required to assist you. A setup description in 4 words is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> Flask and extensions may enable behaviors based on the [environment](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/?production#ENV), such as enabling debug mode.

With debug you will see detailed information about your unhanded
errors, etc.

However this is different when you use production environment.
You should considering configuring [error handlers](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/#generic-exception-handlers) for your application, where you can also log exception traceback.
Code below catches all exceptions and is too generic, just to illustrate the idea.

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_exception(e):
    logging.exception(e)
    # or if you have logger configured
    # app.logger.exception(e)
    return "Internal Server Error", 500
```